# add a play/pause button on a Slideshow only javascript

Tags: javascript, html

hey gys i have this syntax and i want to put a play or pause button  if possible and thanx gys ( sorry if im not clear or if i made any mistake becose im new in stackoveflow and i dont know much );

```
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;

     var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 9000); 
}
```

Comment: Hello Khalil. The kind souls roaming about StackOverflow would definitely appreciate it if you could include what you have tried and if possible, the relevant HTML parts in addition to your javascript code. It'd make it even more convenient for potential helpers if you place the code up on a platform like jsfiddle.net . This way, it saves everyone some time and your question is more likely to get more relevant help with less clarifications :)

Comment: thank you for the advice here is the link to what i did and i didn't try anything becose idont know what to do and thnx again https://jsfiddle.net/wk9m58t3/

Comment: Could you then include your HTML code? Also a link to the carousel library you are using? Most slideshow-style libraries have built-in methods to play and pause slideshows.

Comment: i got this code form this website http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_rr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `setTimeout(carousel, 9000);` on button's OnClick event to start the slideshow and `cleartimeout()` function to stop the slideshow. Refer to [W3School article](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp) This has a similar example for start and stop timer.